# why cant we simply print "print(zip(a,b))"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why can't we print "**print(zip(a,b))**" or simply "**print(c)**"?

```
a=[ "ab", "cd", "ef"]
b=["gh","ij","kl"]
c=zip(a,b)
```

if I try

```
"for i,j in c:
    print(i,j)"
```

**Output:**

**ab gh**

**cd ij**

**ef kl**

But unable to print **"print(c)"**, its giving like this **"zip object at 0x025088C8
"** WHY?

Answer (score 0):

First, your solution won't work because you are considering str only.
What would happen in the following case ?

```
zip([1, 10, 100], ["y", "a", "s"])
```

You can imagine another representation such as:

```
list(zip([1, 10, 100], ["y", "a", "s"]))
>>> [(1, 'y'), (10, 'a'), (100, 's')]
```

But you can read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) in the zip function documentation that this function returns an iterator and this behaviour (in python3) is preferable for multiple reasons such as memory.